# Send IPN only on pending transaction completion for DoExpressCheckoutPayment

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

Is there a way to request an IPN for `DoExpressCheckoutPayment` only if a pending payment completes?  `DoExpressCheckoutPayment` returns the payment status, so there is no point of getting an IPN for payment that completes immediately.  I am requesting an IPN by passing a URL in `PAYMENTREQUEST_n_NOTIFYURL`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IPNs will be triggered for all transactions, but within your IPN script you could add logic so that it only processes IPNs specific to what you're looking for.

Comment: I can do that, but I wanted to avoid the IPN for a completed payment because ```DoExpressCheckoutPayment``` already returns that information.

Comment: There's no way to make IPN not send for specific types or payment status.  You can either enable it or disable it.  If it's enabled it will send all notifications, and you can handle those types/payment statuses within your script as needed.